# How to merge data and create multiple documents?, similar to personalized mailings

Tags: automation, python, csv, database, excel

I would like to use LATEX combined with EXCEL data files (or CSV if it were neccessary) to create "proof of payment".

Supose a list of people

John McEnroe, NYC (USA), 110.23$, 10$,May......
Mary Rose, London, 567.89$, 50$,May.........
.........................................

and what I would like to obtain is a paper similar to
[image]
where you can view the fields of each record of the database.

The question is that I can´t create this.

Could you recommend me any packages or tips to create multiple of this?

Thank you.

I  know that it´s not a concret question. It´s a call of SOS asking for help.

Comment: `textmerg`, `datatool`... [data import topic](http://ctan.org/topic/data-import)

Comment: What's your favourite scripting language? I have a python solution to your problem.

Comment: @MaxNoe I usually compute basically in Mathematica v10, but in the next weeks I´m learningn python, so I´m very interested in your suggestions (mika2ikeATTgmailDOOTTTcom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the mightiest tool in my toolbox is python, I see python problems everywhere. (The "my only tool is a hammer, everything looks like a nail problem".)

The idea is the following:

- A data file, either excel, csv, mysql-database or whatever you like
- A LaTeX-template with placeholders, I used @@key, as two @ should never occure in a document, but you can think of your own.
- A python script that fills the placeholders for each row in the data
  an calls LaTeX to produce the result.

Apart from the standard library you only need `pandas` for the data munching
part. If you want to learn python in the next time and have a scientific background, which i assume if you are using mathematica, i recommend to install
python using the anaconda distribution. 
It comes bundled with nearly all scientific modules und prebuilt dependencies:

http://continuum.io/downloads#py34

This is my `data.csv`:

```
productID,firstname,lastname,date
1,Jules,Winnfield,2015-01-01
2,Vincent,Vega,2015-01-02
```

This is my really simplistic `template.tex`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \item @@productID
  \item @@firstname
  \item @@lastname
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

And this is the python script, please ask if something is not
clear:

```
# codecs provides input/output with specific encoding
import codecs
# os includes operating system operations
import os
# this is needed to call latex from python
from subprocess import call
# pandas for data munching
import pandas

# create folders, no error if it already exists
os.makedirs('tmp', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('output', exist_ok=True)

# read in the template:
with codecs.open('template.tex', encoding='utf8') as f:
    template = f.read()

data = pandas.read_csv('data.csv')
# show the first 5 rows in the data to have a quick look
print(data.head())

# these are the keys we want to replace with our data:
keys = [
    'productID',
    'firstname',
    'lastname',
]

# no we loop over each row to create a pdf with the
# data
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    filled = template
    for key in keys:
        # replace our placeholder with the actual data, cast to string first
        filled = filled.replace('@@' + key, str(row[key]))

    # create a hopefully unique filename
    filename = 'filled_{}_{}_{}'.format(
        row.lastname,
        row.firstname,
        row.date,
    )
    # now we write the filled template to the tmp folder
    with codecs.open('tmp/' + filename + '.tex', 'w', encoding='utf8') as f:
        f.write(filled)

    # and call lualatex or any other latex compiler
    # call takes a list of arguments
    call(['lualatex',
          '--interaction=batchmode',
          '--output-directory=tmp',
          'tmp/' + filename + '.tex',
          ])

    # there is a missing newline at the end of the latex call
    print('\n')

    # now move the file to the output folder:
    os.rename('tmp/' + filename + '.pdf', 'output/' + filename + '.pdf')

# now we delete the tmp folder
call(['rm', '-rf', 'tmp'])
```

pandas also provides `read_excel`, `read_sql_table`, `read_sql_query` and many more: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html

Comment: thank you very much, I think that your solution is very good. I´m trying it in the next weeks. Thank you very much for all your suggestions and advises. I downloaded anaconda as you suggested. If you could give me more suggesttions or advises, please email me at mike2ikeATTgmailDOOTTTcom